# How to access email from email server and store them in database

Tags: asp.net, email

I want to store my messages received on my email account in my own database, so that I can view those emails in application of asp.net made by me.

**How to retrieve those messages from email server and store them in SQL Server database.**

Comment: email server is POP3 or IMAP ?

Answer (score 1):

You might find that the emails are deleted from the mail server when your email client retrieves them. e.g. if you have outlook pointing at your mail account and it retrieves the emails your application will no longer be able to get them.

You can set up an auto forward rule to forward onto another email address. Then your application could retrieve from that.

I have used this for retrieving mail off the mail server http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/